# Primitive type casting in java (disconcerting examples)

Tags: java, casting

I've read most of the threads on this site concerning typecasting (please do not link me to any more or mark this as a duplicate), and would like an explanation on some of these specific cases.

1)

```
char x='a';
char y = 'b';
```

In this case, we are not allowed to do

```
char z = x + y; \\case 1a
```

But we can do

```
char z='a'+'b'; \\ case 1b
```

I read on this site that the addition of two chars results in an int, and that is why we cannot do 1a, but if so, why can we do 1b.

2)

Why is this allowed

```
byte byteVar = 42;
```

The literal 42 is an int, so why are we allowed to store it in a byte without casting even though 42 is in the range of byte. If this can be done, why can't 1a be done.

3)
The following returns true

```
System.out.println(6.0000000000000000000000000000000001 == 6.0);
```

The RHS is treated as a literal double. I'm guessing that the LHS is treated as a literal double as well, but it definitely exceeds the precision allowed for a double. Why isn't an error thrown and how are the two things compared.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on this. Thank you.

Comment: What error would you *expect* the final example to cause? Can you justify that with the use of either of those literals outside the comparison, or by appealing to the Java Language Specification?

Comment: I thought you would get the same error as when you tried to do something like long a = 3000000000;

Comment: That gives an error because the value is out of *range*. 6.0000000000000000000000000000000001 certainly isn't out of the *range* of `double`.

Comment: (And note that the `long` part of that example is irrelevant - 3000000000 is being treated as a 32-bit integer literal; if you make it 3000000000L it's fine, and you have to go to a much larger number to make it out of range of 64-bit integers.)

Comment: So how does a compiler treat a double like 6.0000000000000000000000000000000001 that exceeds its precision but not its range.

Comment: The same as any other value that can't be precisely represented: it uses the closest value. Otherwise `double d = 0.1;` would have to fail to compile as well, for example.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String- for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are handled by the same case - [JLS section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

The third is simply a case of regular conversion from a literal in source code to a `double`: the nearest exact `double` to 6.0000000000000000000000000000000001 is 6.0. So if you had:

```
double d = 6.0000000000000000000000000000000001;
```

that would assign a value of 6.0 to `d`, as that's the closest representable `double` to the value specified in the source code.

Comment: Thanks. To be sure, the expression x+y does not work because it is a variable expression while 'a' +'b' works because it is a constant expression, and so is 42.

Comment: @johnson: Indeed. But it's worth being aware that if you make `x` and `y` static final fields initialized with constant values, then `x + y` would be classified as a constant expression too, and it would be valid to write `char c = x + y;` in that case.

Comment: It's enough to make `x` and `y` final to make them constant values, as they are [initialized with a constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) :) -- *A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression* -- Thus `final char x='X'; final char y='Y'; char z=x+y;` is valid in a method body.

Comment: @HuguesM.: True - for some reason I'd always thought instance fields were non-constant regardless of initialization. Thanks for that.